# Veryfing signature generated by BouncyCastle on PC using native Java JCE

Tags: java, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I am using BouncyCastle to generate a DSA signature but using the native JCE to verify the it.

**NOTE:** I am working with a j2me client that does not natively support signing hence the need for BouncyCastle)

So, on the client the signature is generated as follows:

```
DSASigner sig = new DSASigner();
sig.init(true, privateKey);
String plaintext = "This is the message being signed";
BigInteger[] sigArray = sig.generateSignature(plaintext.getBytes());
...
```

`sigArray` contains 2 `BigIntegers` r and s.

This signature then has to be transmitted to a server which uses native JCE to verify the sig. On the server side, using the native Java JCE, it should be possible to verify a signature as follows:

```
...
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA");
byte[] sigbytes = Base64.decode(signature);
sig.initVerify(publicKey);
sig.update(plaintext.getBytes());
sig.verify(sigbytes)
```

The problem am having is: how do i encode `sigArray` into a format that can be sent to the pc/server as a single Base64 string (instead of separately as r and s) that can then be verified on the server using the native JCE method show in the second snippet of code?

So far i have tried to create DERObjects from the r,s arrays (separately, together as one array, encoded) but still no luck. Anybody faced this before? How did you tackle it?

Answer (score 0):

According to *Cryptographic Message Syntax Algorithms* ([RFC 3370](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3370.txt)) the DSA signature encoding is an ASN.1 sequence containing both integers `r` and `s`:

```
Dss-Sig-Value ::= SEQUENCE {
  r INTEGER,
  s INTEGER }
```